# Dilemma in job and internship offers from the same company

Tags: salary, job-offer, raise

I've got a job offer from a company and agreed for a specific salary. I then participated in a national level competition held by the same company and was one of the finalists. In response to my performance in the competition, the same company have again asked me my willingness to join the company for job/internship and asked me how much I expect to get paid for job/internship.They have also asked me if I'm willing to patent my idea with the company. Can I utilize this situation to ask for a better offer(if so, how do I go about it) or would it just risk the job offer I have at hand. Also is it worth to do an internship in the same company you're already offered a job in?

Comment: *A bird in the hand is worth more than two in the bush* - Take the job. One year down the road is a short time for that elusive pay rise

Comment: I have the option to do both the internship and take the job. But will it be worthwhile doing both?

Answer (score 6):

Take the job, hold off on the patent, then discuss it once you are fully employed.

Comment: So whats you're take on the internship, is there any point in doing an internship for a company in which you have already landed a job. Will the internship add value to my profile or is it pointless. I'd have to join for the job immediately after the internship.

Comment: No, no point in it at all.  Go for the job, not the internship